# Read json data to datasource variable from kendo datasource method

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

In my asp.net i used following method to read Json data from js file,

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "http://localhost:2544/JS/employee.js", dataType: "jsonp"
                    }
                }
            });
            ds.read();
            alert(ds.view().length);
```

Which returns alays 0 to me. I want to pass the column values to draw the graph.
But unable to read the data itself.

Below is my json data which saved in employee.js file

```
{
  "t1": [
    {
      "country": "United States",
      "year": "19994",
      "value": 4.9
    },
    {
      "country": "United States",
      "year": "1995",
      "value": 9.2
    },
   ------
```

And i use scripts in head as follows,

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/styles/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cann't read a JS File through URL , Add a Function in your employee.js

eg :

```
function EmployeeData(){
 return [{
      "country": "United States",
      "year": "19994",
      "value": 4.9
    },
    {
      "country": "United States",
      "year": "1995",
      "value": 9.2
    }]
}
```

Call this from the Datasource

```
var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data:EmployeeData()
            });
            ds.read();
            alert(ds.view().length);
```

make sure to include the employee.js  in the scripts head